# Scrapy Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a probleme with scrapy, it's not returning any results, i don't know where is the probleme

I use Python Version  : 2.7.3 ( Windows 8.1 64 bit )

my project has been created by this command scrapy startproject craigslist_sample

### Project directory :

```
craigslist_sample/
    scrapy.cfg           

    craigslist_sample/            
        __init__.py

        items.py          

        pipelines.py      

        settings.py       

        spiders/         
            __init__.py
              byub.py
```

### My spider file (byub.py)

```
    import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "craig"
        allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
        start_urls = [
            "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo"    ]

        def parse(self, response):
          items = []
          for sel in response.xpath('//p//a[@class="hdrlnk"]'):
               item = CraigslistSampleItem()
               print(  sel.xpath('text()').extract())
               print (sel.xpath('@href').extract())
```

When i put F5 to see my data printed, i have nothing displayed

### My **init**.py file in spiders folder :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../craigslist_sample/")
```

I have added the path ../../craigslist_sample/ to call my CraigslistSampleItem class

### My items.py file

```
import scrapy


class CraigslistSampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link  = scrapy.Field()
```

My Log File :

```
2015-06-20 22:34:59 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: craigslist_sample)
2015-06-20 22:34:59 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-06-20 22:34:59 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'craigslist_sample.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['craigslist_sample.spiders'], 'LOG_STDOUT': True, 'LOG_FILE': '/tmp/scrapy_output.txt', 'BOT_NAME': 'craigslist_sample'}
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-06-20 22:35:00 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo> (referer: None)
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083113578.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083098605.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083051162.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083044559.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083043239.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083034151.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082961277.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082936118.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082930994.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082908649.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082826886.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082820427.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082808607.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082796023.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082767892.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082699233.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082685178.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082682792.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082674781.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082565558.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082545852.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082466564.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082457151.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082454103.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082452290.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082452087.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082442715.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082368243.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082367400.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082364446.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082206212.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082176091.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082142295.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081546128.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081544083.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081349969.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081337282.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081329478.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081325271.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081315033.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081284397.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081272495.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081248716.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081242306.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081198308.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081185072.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081182362.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081039111.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081033894.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081030919.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080930010.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080922969.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080783300.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080757424.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080754908.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080696793.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080523544.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080474373.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079764803.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079655298.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079652979.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079651750.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079617063.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079600458.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079484883.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079458099.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079439949.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079434763.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079423265.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079421733.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079345334.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079272799.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079271027.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079130762.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079058773.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078791191.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078784316.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078657036.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078096040.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078022877.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078018145.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077960434.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077955778.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077927644.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077906229.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077813126.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077799125.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077795848.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077763673.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077582518.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077522272.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077402309.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077397915.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077350438.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077123591.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076362090.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076361296.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076341213.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076299050.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076222757.html']
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15530,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 20, 35, 2, 312000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 209,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 20, 35, 0, 968000)}
2015-06-20 22:35:02 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2015-06-20 23:03:37 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: craigslist_sample)
2015-06-20 23:03:37 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-06-20 23:03:37 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'craigslist_sample.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['craigslist_sample.spiders'], 'LOG_STDOUT': True, 'LOG_FILE': '/tmp/scrapy_output.txt', 'BOT_NAME': 'craigslist_sample'}
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-06-20 23:03:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo> (referer: None)
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083113578.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083098605.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083051162.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083044559.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083043239.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5083034151.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082961277.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082936118.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082930994.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082908649.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082826886.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082820427.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082808607.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082796023.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082767892.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082699233.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082685178.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082682792.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082674781.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082565558.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082545852.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082466564.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082457151.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082454103.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082452290.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082452087.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082442715.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082368243.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082367400.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082364446.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082206212.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082176091.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5082142295.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081546128.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081544083.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081349969.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081337282.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081329478.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081325271.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081315033.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081284397.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081272495.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081248716.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081242306.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081198308.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081185072.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081182362.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081039111.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081033894.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5081030919.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080930010.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080922969.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080783300.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080757424.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080754908.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080696793.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080523544.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5080474373.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079764803.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079655298.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079652979.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079651750.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079617063.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079600458.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079484883.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079458099.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079439949.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079434763.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079423265.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079421733.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079345334.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079272799.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079271027.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079130762.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5079058773.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078791191.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078784316.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078657036.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078096040.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078022877.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5078018145.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077960434.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077955778.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077927644.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077906229.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077813126.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077799125.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077795848.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077763673.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077582518.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077522272.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077402309.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077397915.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077350438.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5077123591.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076362090.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076361296.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076341213.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076299050.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: [u'/sfc/npo/5076222757.html']
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [stdout] INFO: []
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 15536,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 21, 3, 39, 743000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 209,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 21, 3, 38, 303000)}
2015-06-20 23:03:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: please paste the full log output: the lines you've pasted are truncated. try outputting to a log file: -l scrapy.log

Comment: I have edited my question can you see my new log i have made as you said ( The Full log )

Comment: Please update the spider code above too. The indentation in that file is inconsistent as it appears here.

Comment: I have updated it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you search inside each `<p>` there is `<a>` tag which has url but it doesn't have text inside it. Check the HTML of the website. So you are getting incorrect `<a>` tag.

I am searching for `<a>` tag with class `class="hdrlnk"` and it has url and text.

```
for sel in response.xpath('//p//a[@class="hdrlnk"]'):
    print sel.xpath('text()').extract()
    print sel.xpath('@href').extract()
```

Output:

```
[u'Resident Services Coordinator']
[u'/sfc/npo/5083113578.html']
[u'Resident Services Coordinator']
[u'/sfc/npo/5083098605.html']
[u'General Manager - 939/951 Eddy']
[u'/sfc/npo/5083051162.html']
[u'General Manager - 430 Turk']
[u'/sfc/npo/5083044559.html']
....
```

**Update**

1. I created same project as you have. (`scrapy startproject craigslist_sample`)
2. I removed everything from file `spiders/__init__.py`
3. Updated spider

byub.py file

```
import scrapy
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo"    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//p//a[@class="hdrlnk"]'):
           item = CraigslistSampleItem()
           item['title'] =  sel.xpath('text()').extract()
           item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
           items.append(item)
        return items
```

Logs:

```
2015-06-20 22:01:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo>
{'link': [u'/sfc/npo/5083113578.html'],
 'title': [u'Resident Services Coordinator']}
2015-06-20 22:01:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo>
{'link': [u'/sfc/npo/5083098605.html'],
 'title': [u'Resident Services Coordinator']}
2015-06-20 22:01:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/npo>
{'link': [u'/sfc/npo/5083051162.html'],
 'title': [u'General Manager - 939/951 Eddy']}
...
```

To run crawler, I run `scrapy crawl --logfile logs craig` from same folder where `scrapy.cfg` is.

To run crawler with different log level `scrapy crawl --logfile logs -L DEBUG craig`

Comment: I hope you used `item['title'] = ` and `item['link'] = ` instead of `print`.

Comment: Yes i have used like that : 
 def parse(self, response):
      items = []
      for sel in response.xpath('//p//a[@class="hdrlnk"]'):
           item = CraigslistSampleItem()
           item['title'] =  sel.xpath('text()').extract()
           item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
           items.append(item)
           return items

Comment: i have change only the content of the xpath and still the probleme

Comment: Maybe just try to add same print lines as I have, just to check if the data is there.

Comment: I have made this code 
def parse(self, response):
          items = []
          for sel in response.xpath('//p//a[@class="hdrlnk"]'):
               item = CraigslistSampleItem()
               print(  sel.xpath('text()').extract())
               print (sel.xpath('@href').extract()) 
but nothing display when i put F5 so the data doesn't exist i don't know where is the probleme the code is correct

Comment: @JohnLow try ThePavolC's spider code and please note the indentation, four spaces for each indent.

Comment: I also noticed that your logs are set to `INFO` level, try to set it to `DEBUG`, maybe there's going to be some info.

Comment: @ThePavolC i have added this line LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'  to change INFO to debug in settings.py in my project folder but it doesn't work always i have INFO AND about from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem i was make like that in the first time but always i had import error no name module called craigslist_sample.items and by searching in the net i have add the path in the __init.py__ and the probleme was solved for now i will need more information about my probleme by making debug mode can you help me please

Comment: Can you make as me, i mean by deleting  from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem and adding 
 import sys
sys.path.append("../../craigslist_sample/") to __init__.py and see if it still work

Comment: can you tell me the version of your python and OS 64 or 32 ? because i have windows 8.1 64 bit and python 2.7.3

Comment: Then it doesn't work for me, it can't find reference to `CraigslistSampleItem`. You shouldn't really be modifying __init__.py

Comment: Ubuntu 64, Python 2.7.6, Scrapy 1.0.0

Comment: i think the probleme is in my OS or my python should be 2.7.6 anyway can you give me the way how i can set debug mode and thank you so mush

Comment: To run crawler with different log level `scrapy crawl -L DEBUG craig`

Comment: i accept your answer because it works in your home and i will restart my instalation to another OS and another version of python Thank you !! at least I know now the probleme is from my windows or my python version but exactly where i don't know :D

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your spider `return items` is indented too far and needs to be:-

```
for sel in response.xpath('//p'):
    item = CraigslistSampleItem()
    # ...

return items
```

Also try doing `scrapy crawl craig -o results.json` to output the items into the file named `results.json`.

Comment: i have edited my code but always the same probleme the results.json file is empty